# I can't install php with Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I want to install php on my Mac but when I run `brew install php` I get the Error:

```
Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /private/tmp/d20210914-2252-l2ywg/openssl@1.1/. /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1` exited with 1. Here's the output:
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20210914-2252-l2ywg/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l/LICENSE: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210914-2252-l2ywg/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l/bin: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/./1.1.1l/bin: No such file or directory
...
```

I am using the latest MacOS beta.

Comment: The error is clear: "Permission denied"
Did you try to run command with "sudo" ?

Comment: Yes, but Homebrew doesn't support sudo.

Comment: sudo is separate command, it's not related to homebrew at all.
It's just allow to run command "As administrator"

Comment: Yes, I know what sudo does and that it's a seperate command, but like I already said,  Homebrew doesn't support sudo:
`Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
`

Comment: I get the same error. How did you fix it?